# Android fragment commit illegal state exception only when phone is locked

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception, android-actionbaractivity

I am committing a fragment on receiving a broadcast, such as

```
 BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Log.e(TAG,"inside onReceive");
            if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(
                    DATA_AVAILABLE))
                initFragments.run();
                }
     }
```

InitFragment is a runnable with code

```
dataBrowse = new SongListFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        ./*replace*/ add (R.id.container, dataBrowse ).commit();
```

It works all the time perfect, and except when the phone is locked. Why this happens? What could be the solution of this cause?

The log :

```
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=dat_avail flg=0x10 } in com.example.MainActivity$1@41b98e90
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:765)
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1343)
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1361)
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174):    at com.example.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:228)
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174):    at com.example.MainActivity$1.onReceive(MainActivity.java:101)
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:755)
06-23 03:56:38.210: E/AndroidRuntime(11174):    ... 9 more
06-23 03:56:38.245: I/Process(11174): Sending signal. PID: 11174 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a state loss occurring in your program, one of the solution is to save the instance and restore the intstance which avoid state loss and another is to commit allowing state loss you can have a look at the blogspot [Fragment Transactions & Activity State Loss](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html)

Comment: what would be the effect of `commit allowing stateloss` if i have not set `setRetainState` ?

Comment: Use commitAllowingStateLoss() only as a last resort. The only difference between calling commit() and commitAllowingStateLoss() is that the latter will not throw an exception if state loss occurs. Usually you don't want to use this method because it implies that there is a possibility that state loss could happen. The better solution, of course, is to write your application so that commit() is guaranteed to be called before the activity's state has been saved, as this will result in a better user experience.